# Is it possible to emulate variadic generics in Rust?

Tags: templates, generics, rust, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Rust is missing Variadic Generics (and also variadic functions) as a language feature.

Since it doesn't directly support these, is it possible to emulate the behavior in some way?

I suspect this might be possible with macros, but I don't have a detailed understanding of them (yet) so I can't (yet) sketch out a design suggestion.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with macros; it will help if you will give an example of where you want to emulate them.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: you are trying to do something, you know how to do that in an other language (presumably, C++) and realize Rust is not C++, so you ask "how to emulate the C++ feature in Rust". However, there may be a better solution in Rust than to emulate C++. Please give us some context about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Nightly Rust actually DOES support variadic functions in order to be able to interoperate with C. The feature is [c_variadic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/c-variadic.html)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, maybe this is not, in the end, what you need.
But in case this can help, here are two trivial examples of variadic macro.

One considers the variable arguments as a whole (as the content of an array), another explicitly considers each argument separately thanks to (compile-time) recursion.

Note that these examples only intend to illustrate the idea.
They are very bad since they make strong choices about the involved types and do not even consider what happens in terms of ownership (borrowing/moving).

The details about the syntax and logic for such kind of declarative macros can be found in [this document](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros.html).

```rust
macro_rules! i32_addition {
    ($($values:expr),*) => {
        [$($values),*].iter().sum::<i32>()
    };
}

macro_rules! text_addition {
    ($value:expr) => {
        $value.to_string()
    };
    ($head:expr, $($tail:expr),*) => {
        $head.to_string() + &text_addition!($($tail),*)
    };
}

fn main() {
    let r1 = i32_addition!(1, 2, 3, 5, 7);
    println!("{:?}", r1);
    let r2 = i32_addition!(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13);
    println!("{:?}", r2);
    let r3 = text_addition!("1", "2", "3", "5", "7");
    println!("{:?}", r3);
    let r4 = text_addition!("1", "2", "3", "5", "7", "11", "13");
    println!("{:?}", r4);
}
/*
18
42
"12357"
"123571113"
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write the macros yourself, there's a crate with heterogenous lists: [frunk](https://docs.rs/frunk/latest/frunk)

```rust
struct Variadic<H: HList> {
  xs: H,
}
```